# Visual Studio 2017 external tool parameters

Tags: eclipse, git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, eclipse-neon

I use Visual Studio 2017 for GIT. If I compare a file, it opens in Winmerge. If it's a new Java file, I'd like to open it in the instance of Eclipse that is currently running. Is that possible? In Visual Studio, I can do "Open With", and provide an Exe and Arguments along with it.

I tried passing the following as arguments:

- /root, "$(ItemPath)"
- "$(ItemPath)"
- $(ItemPath)

For all of the above, Eclipse responds with something like: The file '$(ItemPath)' could not be found.

Comment: Can you provide more details like how is java file related to workspace and project towards eclipse? Also note you can't have java file in Eclipse without the file being in a java project.

Comment: I have the workspace and project open in Eclipse at the same time

Comment: I doubt you can't point to your running eclipse instance but I have [something](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/OpenFileFeature#Windows) for you

Comment: I think that the issue is on the Visual Studio side. I thought that VS would convert the $(ItemPath) to the file name as per this vs2015 document. Haven't found a 2017 document yet https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx